# An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection on server side

Tags: c#, server, .net-6.0, windows-server

I have build console application(.Net 6.0) which is sending report to few email accounts. It does work locally on my laptop, however, on the server is giving me the following exception:

```
[!] [19.6.2023 08:20:54] - An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.

The server's SSL certificate could not be validated for the following reasons:
• The server certificate has the following errors:
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
• An intermediate certificate has the following errors:
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
• An intermediate certificate has the following errors:
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
```

Server: Windows Server 2022 Standard
Version: 21H2

What could be the issue?

Comment: It could be that the Root CA Certificate needs installing on the server where you are running this (for all users).

Comment: That is the first step I did, I transferred all certificates from my local laptop to the server, but it didn't fix the problem :\. I'm thinking maybe any TCP port needs to be enabled?

Comment: It looks like the problem was with Sophos firewall, now the application is working.